# How do I align my pagination properly?

Tags: html, css, pagination

I want to align my pagination so that it'll be at the center of the page. How ever, some parts of it won't align even though I placed them in the same div. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
<div class="center">  
<ul class="pagination">

<a>Page: </a> <?php echo $pages; if($_GET['category'] != ''){?>
<a href="<?php echo $currentURL;?>View/All" 
<?php if($action == "ViewAll"){echo 'style="font-weight:bold;color:#000;text-decoration:none;"';}?>>
View All</a><?php }?>
</ul>
</div>    
</div>

<style>

ul.pagination {
display: inline-block;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
padding-top: 300px;
}

 ul.pagination {
}


ul.pagination p{display: inline;}

ul.pagination a {
color: black;
float: left;
padding: 8px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
transition: background-color .3s;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

ul.pagination p a.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
}

ul.pagination p a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #ddd;}



</style>
```

Comment: it could perhaps be useful if you replace the php code with some html content, by now the only things I see in the layout are a "Page:" and a "View/All" rectangles. do you want that to be centered?

Comment: Where are your `li` tags? `a` can not be a direct child of `ul` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Answer (score 0):

Your div by default will be as wide as the page (or whatever element contains it). Let's assume that it will be wider than you pagination. In order to center it.

Give the "ul" a specific width and set a "margin: 0 auto" for it. It will center itself in the container (div) as long as you don't float anything inside it.